# vncserver has to be restarted to see new unix groups

Tags: linux, group, vnc

I have been using VNC to remote desktop into my linux work machines for at least 15 years now. When I am added to a unix group, I have simply started a new terminal on my VNC. I have recently switched companies and as I am added to various new unix groups, I am required to restart my vncserver to see the changes. This is crazy. I have to shutdown everything I am working on, or juggle multiple vncs while I migrate to the new one. I haven't even successfully migrated my work before being added to yet another unix group, and now am up to 4 vnc sessions and I'm already losing my mind. I have asked our IT department and they seem surprised that it could be any other way. When I asked my IT friends at my old companies, they are surprised that groups update requires a restart, so now I am just asking the internet.

Comment: i noticed this too, with RHEL7 and a paid for version of VNC not the free version

Comment: We are using CentOS 7, but also have CentOS 6 machines with the same behavior.  I don't know if we are paying for VNC, but I've only worked for extremely large corporations, so I'd hope that they have been paying for it.  Glad to hear I am not alone.

Comment: I'm facing the same under RedHat EL 8.x.
I hoped I was doing something wrong and this is not a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue on redhat 7.7

As a temporary workaround you can use "newgrp your_group_name" to add yourself to the group. Unfortunately this only persists in the terminal window.

As a less temporary workaround you can update your .bashrc (or equivalent) to automatically newgrp every time a terminal is opened. This will save you frustration when you open a new terminal and forget to newgrp.

Comment: I believe newgrp required me to enter my password so I couldn't put it in my .zshrc.  I actually left that company a while back, so can't test it.  I haven't run into the issue at my new workplace.  One of those mysteries that may forever remain a mystery.